How can I overlay a component inside a LazyColumn?
I would like to get an effect of cards that are supposed to be placed so that when I expand each one of them, the others are collapsed again. I have managed to make the effect, but I have a small visual problem that I can't solve.

As you can see, there is a blank hole due to the rounded corners, and I would like the background of the card that is behind at the top to fill that hole instead of looking white. My code is this:
@Composable
fun RecipeScreen() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            //no-op
        }

        ExpandableBottomCards(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun ExpandableBottomCards(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var expandedCard by remember { mutableStateOf("Ingredients") }
    val cards = listOf("Ingredients", "Direction", "Tools")

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.Transparent)
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(cards) { index, cardTitle ->
            ExpandableBottomCard(
                title = cardTitle,
                isExpanded = expandedCard == cardTitle,
                onCardClick = {
                    expandedCard = if (expandedCard == cardTitle) "" else cardTitle
                },
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ExpandableBottomCard(
    title: String,
    isExpanded: Boolean,
    onCardClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    val backgroundColor = when (title) {
        "Ingredients" -> Color.Red
        "Direction" -> Color.Blue
        else -> Color.Green
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp))
            .background(backgroundColor)
            .clickable { onCardClick() }
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(60.dp)
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text(text = title, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, color = Color.White)
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Edit,
                contentDescription = "Edit",
                tint = Color.White
            )
        }
        if (isExpanded) {
            Text(
                text = "Contenido expandido para $title",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
                color = Color.White
            )
        }
    }
}

